# Adding transition effect to Div rollover

Tags: html, transition

I have set up the following html and css to create a div that changes content on hover.  I want to add a simple transition to the hover as follows:

`transition: .5s ease;`

But I am having no success getting it to work.

My html is as follows:

```
<div class="top-box">
<div style="text-align: center;">
<i class="fa fa-laptop round-background"><!-- icon --></i>
<hr class="boxline" />
<p class="top-box-text">MY SERVICES</p>
</div>

<div class="bottom-box">
<p class="box-header">CONTENT DEVELOPMENT</p>
<ul class="box-icons">
<li>SERVICE</li>
<li>SERVICE</li>
<li>SERVICE</li>
<li><a class="box-link" href="#">READ MORE</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
.bottom-box, .top-box:hover>div {
    display: none;
}

.top-box:hover>.bottom-box {
    display: block;
}

.top-box {
    border: 5px solid #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #000 inset;
    color:#000; 
    height:445px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    background:#CEA453;
}

.bottom-box {
    border: 5px solid #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #000 inset;
    margin:-5px -15px;
    background:#fff;
    height:445px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}

.top-box-text {
    font-weight:600;
}

.boxline {
    display: block;
    border-top: 1px solid #000;
    margin: 1em 3em;
    padding: 0;
}

.round-background {
    background: #960;
    border-radius: 100%;
    border: 8px solid #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.40);
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 60px !Important;
    padding: 32px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 140px;
    width:140px;
    margin:60px 0 20px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}

.box-header {
    background:#960; 
    text-align:center;
    padding:1em 0;
    color:#fff;
    font-weight:600;
}

.box-icons, .box-icons li {
     padding: 0;
     margin: 0;
     list-style: none;
}

.box-icons li {
  margin: 1em;
  margin-left: 3em;
  line-height:1em;
  position: relative;
}

.box-icons li:before {
  content: '\f067'; /* fa-plus */
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  float: left;
  margin-left: -1.5em;
  color: #CEA453;
}

.box-link {
    color:#960;
    font-weight:600;
}

.box-link:active, .box-link:hover {
    color:#CEA453;
}
```

The layout I have created works fine but I want to add some transition to the rollover to soften the hover effect.

I am a newbie so any help any one can give is appreciated greatly.

I should mention that I have three of these boxes sitting side by side by adding grid-33 class to the top-box div.  I didn't paste all of the code here because it is rather large.

I have achieved a transition on hover using the following CSS:

```
 .bottom-box, .top-box:hover>div {
        opacity: 0;
        height: 0;
        visibility: hidden;
        transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
}

.top-box:hover>.bottom-box {
    opacity: 1;
        height: auto;
        visibility: visible;
        transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
}
```

However the problem is now that content under the top box is pushed down (when not hovered) in tablet or phone view.  Everything works as it should in full screen.

Comment: I'm a bit confused.. you're transitioning on opacity. So why are you changing height and visibility? opacity: 0 to opacity: 1 will do the trick. You don't need all the other stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a transition on the display property. You should use opacity or something else like this example:

```css
.bottom-box, .top-box:hover>div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left:0;
    right: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.5s linear;
    opacity: 0;
}

.top-box:hover>.bottom-box {
    top: 0;
    left:0;
    right: 0;
    position: absolute;
    transition: opacity 0.5s linear;
    opacity: 1;
}

.top-box {
    border: 5px solid #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #000 inset;
    color:#000; 
    height:445px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    background:#CEA453;
}

.bottom-box {
    border: 5px solid #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #000 inset;
    margin:-5px -15px;
    background:#fff;
    height:445px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}

.top-box-text {
    font-weight:600;
}

.boxline {
    display: block;
    border-top: 1px solid #000;
    margin: 1em 3em;
    padding: 0;
}

.round-background {
    background: #960;
    border-radius: 100%;
    border: 8px solid #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.40);
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 60px !Important;
    padding: 32px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 140px;
    width:140px;
    margin:60px 0 20px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}

.box-header {
    background:#960; 
    text-align:center;
    padding:1em 0;
    color:#fff;
    font-weight:600;
}

.box-icons, .box-icons li {
     padding: 0;
     margin: 0;
     list-style: none;
}

.box-icons li {
  margin: 1em;
  margin-left: 3em;
  line-height:1em;
  position: relative;
}

.box-icons li:before {
  content: '\f067'; /* fa-plus */
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  float: left;
  margin-left: -1.5em;
  color: #CEA453;
}

.box-link {
    color:#960;
    font-weight:600;
}

.box-link:active, .box-link:hover {
    color:#CEA453;
}
```

```html
<div class="top-box">
    <div style="text-align: center;">
    <i class="fa fa-laptop round-background"><!-- icon --></i>
    <hr class="boxline" />
    <p class="top-box-text">MY SERVICES</p>
</div>

<div class="bottom-box">
    <p class="box-header">CONTENT DEVELOPMENT</p>
    <ul class="box-icons">
      <li>SERVICE</li>
      <li>SERVICE</li>
      <li>SERVICE</li>
      <li><a class="box-link" href="#">READ MORE</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your input.  I was including heights etc in the rollover code because that is what the help desk for my theme supplied to me.  I have just tried without the height settings and everything works.